# Custom font is not applied to the Nativescript blank template

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have tried a nativescript project for a week. I created a blank nativescript template from cli and use VSCode to code.

This is the command line that I use.

```
tns create my-app-name --template tns-template-blank-ts
```

I found the problem with custom fonts. I search from everywhere that I just create a "fonts" folder inside the app folder like this

```
/my-project/app/fonts
```

However, due to creating from blank template, the template has relocated the app folder inside the src folder like this.

```
/my-project/src/app
```

Of course, the SourceRoot folder has been changed to "src" folder.
I put "fonts" folder into the "src" folder instead. and put font "RSU" into "fonts" folder

Next, I wrote the css class for the font in file "app.css".

```
.rsu{
    font-family: 'RSU', 'RSU-Regular';
    font-size: 22;
}
```

and add the class to the Label element in "home.component.html"

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Home"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout class="page">
    <!-- Add your page content here -->
    <label class="rsu" text="Hello World"></label>
</GridLayout>
```

So, the font hasn't been changed.
I attached pics for this problem.

https://www.imgtrue.com/image/UIfgLE

https://www.imgtrue.com/image/UIfiKC

https://www.imgtrue.com/image/UIfTXV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
.rsu {
    font-family: 'RSU-Regular', 'RSU_Regular';
    font-size: 22;
}
```

Android relies on file name and iOS is on the font family name. So it's recommended to use rename your font file with font's name Or pass both font and file name separated by comma.